# Onfocusout problems

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function that is triggered when the `onfocusout` attribute of an input field is called, which works perfectly.

The only problem I have is that at the first time, whenever the user inputs a text, after executing the JavaScript function, the value of the input disappears from the screen, so the user has to input it a second time.

How can I solve this?

```
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" onfocusout="passcheck(0)" title="input must not be less than 8 characters" required></input>

function passcheck(type){ 
    var status=false;
    switch(type) {
    case 1:     
    var divP=document.getElementById("form-group password");

  if(!document.getElementById("passHelp"))
    divP.innerHTML+="<small id='passHelp' hidden class='form-text text-muted' color='red'>Password mismatch.</small>";

    if(!status){ document.getElementById("passHelp").hidden=false;

  document.getElementById("passHelp").style.color="Red";
            }
           else{ document.getElementById("passHelp").hidden=true; }
           break;} 
return status; }
```

Comment: Add some code, we can't identify your problem without seeing it.

Comment: I'm new here... I'm not so use to setting up the code thing

Comment: What you did is correct. I'll take a look

Comment: Or is it my browser, cause I tried it on Chrome and Internet explorer, same thing

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the code you provided. Is there more to it?

Comment: Their's a part that uses ajax but it's another case of the switch statement, like could the ajax call be the problem, it's (ajax) working fine o